# hide svg segment before animation

Tags: svg

I have an SVG animation here: http://jsfiddle.net/LANjy/3 with the following code.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Animating pen strokes in svg</title>
  <style>
    .tekst { 
      fill:none;
      stroke:red;
      stroke-width:2px;
      stroke-linecap:round;
    }
    text { 
      font-size:40px;
      font-family:stix;
      text-anchor:middle;
    }
  </style>
  <g id="layer1">
    <path id="strikeout1" class='tekst' d="M 398,390 L 400,400">
      <animate id="first" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="" to="0"
      dur="2s" begin="2s"
onload="var length = parentNode.getTotalLength();
                   parentNode.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',length+','+length);
                   this.setAttribute('from',length)" />
    </path>
    <path fill="none" id="strikeout2" class='tekst' d="M400,380 L398,390">
      <animate id="second" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="0"
      fill="freeze" dur="1s" begin="first.end" onload="var length = parentNode.getTotalLength();
                   parentNode.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',length+','+length);
                   this.setAttribute('from',length);" />
    </path>
  </g>

  <rect id="rect" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" pointer-events="all"/>
</svg>
```

The animation begins 1 second after page load, but you'll notice that each segment is visible before the animation begins. How do I have them appear only after they've been animated?

Comment: You're using JavaScript, so the first thing you want to do is put your code in a script block, not using inline code. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/LANjy/3 (this doesn't solve your problem, but makes it much easier for people to help you, and for you to keep working on this)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get a `load` event on the `animate` element, only the root svg and elements that have external references should ever see such an event.

Here's a modified fiddle with the scripting part moved: http://jsfiddle.net/LANjy/5/

To hide the stroke, you can add another animation (e.g a `visibility:hidden` toggle), or you can have a wide gap in the dasharray that you position such that the path initially is made invisible.